# IntelliJ IDEA wrapping settings for one-line anonymous class

Tags: intellij-idea

How to setup IntelliJ IDEA to prevent the splitting of an anonymous class, declared on one line, into several lines during auto-reformating (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)?

For example, to prevent the splitting of

```
x = foo(new Boo() {});
```

into two lines:

```
x = foo(new Boo() {

});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
"File" [menu]/"Settings"/"Code Style"/"Alignment and Braces":
   ==>  "Keep when Reformatting" Field Set:
          Check: "Simple methods in one line"
          Check: "Simple blocks in one line"
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work as expected. Maybe class block is another kind of blocks, than statement blocks.

Comment: Than that's a bug in the IntelliJ version you are using IMHO, since there's no other option than that in the Settings.

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Well, I hope it will be fixed in future versions.

Thank you, Adrian!

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled on this old question when searching for the same. The option **Simple classes in one line** has since been added to IntelliJ.

It can be found in the settings under **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Java** > **Wrapping and Braces**, in the **Keep when reformatting** field set.