# IntelliJ, Java formatting: force empty blocks to be on one line

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to tell IntelliJ to put empty block on one line when formatting Java files.

I'd like this:

```
@Override
public void onClickPositive(int tag, Object payload) {
}
```

To automatically become this:

```
@Override
public void onClickPositive(int tag, Object payload) {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA wrapping settings for one-line anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364757/intellij-idea-wrapping-settings-for-one-line-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no way to do it for reformatting code.

This can only be done manually.

Check your Code Style settings, under "Alignment and Braces" to preserve your formatting.
You should find a "Simple methods in one line" option there. Check it and clear the "Line breaks" check box.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that :(  This feature exists in Eclipse.  Thanks for replying :)

Comment: In IntellijIdea 14.1.5 this option is in "Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Keep when reformatting > Simple {blocks,methods} in one line"

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. As of today (v2020.1) it is still called "Wrapping and Braces", like  _andrybak_ said, but the answer is still correct. I updated all the relevant settings for "simple x in one line", 4 types all in all. Then I did "replace in path" (Shift-Ctrl-R) and in regex mode globally replaced `\{\n\s*\}` by `{ }`. Now I have what I want and some more peace of mind. `:)`

Comment: nice, but how do i preserve the space? `{ }` is what i want, but intellij keeps giving me `{}`

Comment: Code Style > Java > Spaces > Code braces will give you `{ }`

Answer (score 14):

Enable following `Simple blocks in one line` code style in settings.

```sh
Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Keep when reformatting > Simple blocks in one line
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the unnecessary line breaks more universally throughout a project than just remove the newline before curly braces.

First go to the following setting and set a larger value for **hard wrap**:

```
Settings > Editor > Code Style
```

[image: Intellij line length setting]

The default is **120**. Change it to **250** or any other large value.

Next, navigate to the following setting:

```
Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Keep when reformatting > Line breaks
```

[image: Intellij line breaks setting]

Uncheck "line breaks"

Finally, go back to your file and try to reformat the code.

[image: Reformat code]

This removes all the unnecessary line breaks that have been put into the code.