# IntelliJ, Kotlin formatting: force empty blocks to be on one line

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254509/intellij-java-formatting-force-empty-blocks-to-be-on-one-line) however I can't create the same rule set for **Kotlin**.  Kotlin "Code Style" does not have

> Simple blocks in one line

Under its "Keep when reformatting" list

How can I keep `else -> {}` as opposed to

```
else -> {
}
```

For Kotlin styling?

-Otterman

Comment: Might try : `else -> Unit`

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not implemented in Kotlin yet.

It is tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12491